# Tried to delete element by workflow

Tags: workflow

I tried with two list, but It don't work. How could I get a element name and delete this ?

When I Write a element it deleting this but when I getting from lookap field its writing me this masage: **The workflow could not delete the list item. Make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to delete items in the list.**

I tried with two converted numbers and it dont works.

Comment: Does the account your running the workflow as have sufficient access to the list that the lookup value is being pulled in from?

Comment: I think yes because I'm admin. How to fundament aut a Access to acount?

Comment: How could I find out that account can get this workflow ? I Give to everything acces to that list.